# Map through object React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving data from an external api in React

I have an object

```
lend_rates = {
bitfinex : 1.2,
blockfi : 2.3,
celsius : 3,
coinlist : 1.5
}
```

I am trying to map through it so i can render the data i.e it shows on the screen "bitfinex : 1.2, blockfi : 2.3, etc"

```
  metrics.lend_rates.map((rate, i)=>{
        return(
          <div key={i}>
            {rate.key} : {rate.value}
          </div>
        )
      })
```

but im gettin an error saying its not a function.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is defined as metrics?

Comment: Make the object an array to render

Comment: metrics is an object that lend_rates a part of

Answer (score 4):

I guess there's no `.map` function on [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Try with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which returns a mappable array, instead:

```js
Object.entries(lend_rates).map(([ key, value ], i) => 
  <div key={i}>
    {key} : {value}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const lend_rates = {
bitfinex : 1.2,
blockfi : 2.3,
celsius : 3,
coinlist : 1.5
}

const lend_rates_arr = Object.keys(lend_rates);


const newArr = lend_rates_arr.map((rate, idx) => { 
  return { label: [rate], value: Object.values(lend_rates)[idx] }
})

console.log(newArr);

newArr.map(item => console.log(item.label))
```